# Omission of object

Tags: direct-objects

In the following sentence A, is the word "stop" an intransitive verb or a transitive verb?  If it's a transitive verb, should the object word such as that/it be added like in the sentence B?

A: Once a food culture begins to change, it is hard to stop.

B: Once a food culture begins to chabge, it is hard to stop that.

Thank you.

Comment: B sounds very incorrect to me. I think A is technically okay, but I would prefer to rephrase it anyway, for clarity.

Comment: For example: "The snowball of a changing food culture is hard to stop." or "Changes in food cultures are not easily reversed" (slightly different meaning) or "It is difficult to fight against the momentum of a changing food culture."

Comment: Of those three rephrasings, I personally prefer the third.

Comment: The idea you are trying to convey is that there is **momentum** behind changes in food cultures. The analogy of a snowball accumulating snow as it rolls down a hill can convey that idea, but it's not as clear as mentioning momentum directly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*stop* is both [transitive and intransitive.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stop) And frankly, I've come across both the examples as in your question.

Nevertheless, I'd put an object here to remove *ambiguity.* You said, *'..hard to stop.'* but *what?* Your efforts? Your research? Putting an object makes it clear.

> Once a [sic] food culture begins to change, it is hard to stop ***it*** *(i.e. food culture).*